# How to prevent login directly to my defaul desktop?

Tags: lightdm, login-screen, lxde

I installed lxde on my OS. But when I start up my os it doesn't take me to the login screen it just boots to the default DE right away. How do I make it so that I can boot into LXDE right away? Or how do I boot lxde from terminal?

Comment: Have you activated no-password login?

Answer (score 1):

Logging out will bring up the login screen. There, click the icon to the right of your user name to select a new desktop environment. Now you can log in using LXDE, and LXDE should be the default from now on.

Answer (score 0):

You can boot LXDE from console by typing `sudo lightdm`